# Create column inside a loop in R

Tags: r

I have this data.

```
OPENING
2007
2009
2004
```

I want to make the column format like this:

```
OPENING Y2004 Y2005 Y2006 Y2007 Y2008 Y2009
2007                        1    
2009                                    1
2004      1
```

It is possible to create this column step by step with if function, while
I'd like to make loop or lapply function.

How do I use these functions?

Comment: This are called "dummy variables" or "one-hot encoding". If you search those terms you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!